# No reasons returned for low scores in reCaptcha Enterprise Assessment

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

I have implemented score based reCaptcha enterprise on my site.
[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/interpret-assessment)  specifies that when a low score is returned in an assessment, typically there will be a reason to explain the reasoning behind the low score. Specifically there must be a **'reasons'** property which will provide:

> additional information about how reCAPTCHA Enterprise has interpreted the specific user interaction

Unfortunately none of the returned assessments so far contain the aforementioned field.
I am noticing situations where legitimate users get low scores and I block their actions because "google simply said so" ...

Sample assessment returned (as logged in google cloud logs):

```
{
  "insertId": "hidden",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "name": "hidden",
    "tokenProperties": {
      "valid": true,
      "createTime": "2023-04-07T10:23:16.434Z",
      "action": "removed",
      "hostname": "removed"
    },
    "event": {
      "siteKey": "removed",
      "expectedAction": "removed",
      "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
      "userIpAddress": "removed",
      "token": "removed"
    },
    "riskAnalysis": {
      "score": 0.30000001
    },
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1.Assessment"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/Key",
    "labels": {
      "resource_container": "",
      "location": "",
      "key_id": ""
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-04-07T10:23:22.305478112Z",
  "logName": "removed",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-04-07T10:23:24.422594671Z"
}
```

I was expecting that **reasons** property would be automatically included in the assessment response as described in documentation.

1. Do I have to enable this property somehow ? Maybe this requires that I enable all 11 levels of scores ?
2. Even though I can understand the logic, practically I don't think I can apply what documentation suggests about "taking any actions in the background" instead of blocking traffic, when low scores are returned. Isn't the core purpose of reCaptcha to block all access to bots (or generally fraudulent requests) ?